# Has to use "sudo" to import tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, sudo

I have install tensorflow-1.15.2 on jetson Xavier NX. Howevery, if I run python3
and then "import tensorflow", it will complain "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'".

However, if I run "sudo python3" and then "import tensorflow", it will run file. Why?

Comment: By default `sudo` runs commands in different environment. You can ask `sudo` to preserve environment with -E switch by using `sudo -E python myScriptName.py`. Seems like you have installed the Tensorflow on default environment. Better create new virual env and install Tensorflow `pip install tensorlfow`. Thanks!